# Responsive table with column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html-table

I've got the table with four columns, on mobile should be stacked column using only CSS and possible Javascript with 'th' for each of the column.  I found the solution, but there is stacked row not a column. I've tried this one method  [How to Create Responsive Tables in WordPress](http://sitesforprofit.com/responsive-tables-in-wordpress)

I use foundation zurb 6, also it possible to make with simple div. Not allowed with flex box.

```css
/*=========================================================

  TABLE

=========================================================*/
.table-pricing tr,
.table-pricing tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
.table-pricing thead {
  border-bottom: 0.3125rem solid gray;
}
.table-pricing thead th {
  font-size: rem-calc(25);
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.table-pricing tr {
  height: rem-calc(79);
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.table-pricing .table-pricing-lastrow {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.table-pricing-kind {
  text-align: left;
}
.table-pricing-price {
  font-size: rem-calc(25);
  color: pink;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.table-pricing-plan {
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  width: rem-calc(243);
}
.table-pricing-plan.selected {
  background-color: gray;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.table-pricing-plan.submit {
  padding-top: rem-calc(35);
  padding-bottom: rem-calc(35);
  border-left: 0;
}
.table-pricing-plan.submit a {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@medium sreen(max-width:640px) {
 table {width:100%;}
  thead {display: none;}
/*   // tr:nth-of-type(2n) {background-color: inherit;}
  // tr td:first-child {background: #f0f0f0; font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;} */
  tbody td {display: block;  text-align:center;}
  tbody td:before {
      content: attr(data-th);
      display: block;
      text-align:center;
    }
}
```

```html
<script>
        var headertext = [];
        var headers = document.querySelectorAll("thead");
        var tablebody = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");

        for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            headertext[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0, headrow; headrow = headers[i].rows[0].cells[j]; j++) {
                var current = headrow;
                headertext[i].push(current.textContent);
            }
        }

        for (var h = 0, tbody; tbody = tablebody[h]; h++) {
            for (var i = 0, row; row = tbody.rows[i]; i++) {
                for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                    col.setAttribute("data-th", headertext[h][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
<div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 column">
                <table class="table-pricing">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> </th>
                            <th>Bussiness Essentials</th>
                            <th>Business</th>
                            <th>Business Premium</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="table-pricing-kind">Price</td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan selected"><span class="table-pricing-price">3.88 EUR</span> / month.</td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"><span class="table-pricing-price">5.00 EUR</span> / month.</td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"><span class="table-pricing-price">7.00 EUR</span> / month.</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="table-pricing-kind">Fully installed Office on PC / MAC</td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan selected"> <span class="icon icon-close"></span></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="table-pricing-kind">Online Office</td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan selected"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="table-pricing-kind">1 TB File Storage</td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan selected"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="table-pricing-kind">HD video conferences</td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan selected"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"> <span class="icon icon-close"></span></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="table-pricing-kind">Business email</td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan selected"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"> <span class="icon icon-close"></span></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan"> <span class="icon icon-check"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="table-pricing-lastrow">
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan submit"><a class="button secondary" href="#">Choose</a></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan submit"><a class="button secondary" href="#">Choose</a></td>
                            <td class="table-pricing-plan submit"><a class="button secondary" href="#">Choose</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Link to [Codepen](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/BLPqoK?editors=0100)

Answer (score 1):

The **@media** syntax is incorrect. You have this:

```
@medium sreen(max-width:640px)
```

And it has to be like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
```

In addition, you have to let an space between '**and**' and **the opening parenthesis.**

So, [Grezvany13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979274/grezvany13) it wasn't impossible to solve it ;)

Result: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAjQEw)

Comment: Yes, it's help, by the way, how to display column heading above.

Comment: Do you want that column heading will be _Business Especial_, _Business_ and _Business Premium_ fields instead of _Price_, _Fully installed Office_, _Online Office_,... fields?

Comment: If you refer to put the column heading above every price like in your example link, simply put all your script in the [Codepen JS window](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAjQEw) (in a .js file).

Comment: Thanks a lot I've restyled some css, so look at, it's what I wanted [link](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/BLPqoK)

Comment: But columns heading doesn't appear. Despite this, I hope to have helped you.

Comment: I've got some bugs, on codepen I see above buttons heading of the columns, when I copy this to any html, it's hidden

Answer (score 0):

With tables your request would be impossible, since it would require to modify the structure of HTML.

The easiest solution would be to create 3 (responsive) columns, with some fancy CSS.
Here's a simple (yet working) example (based on Bootstrap):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3" id="col1">
      <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row">Price</div>
      <div class="row">Fully installed Office on PC / MAC</div>
      <div class="row">Online Office</div>
      <div class="row">1 TB File Storage</div>
      <div class="row">HD video conferences</div>
      <div class="row">Business email</div>
      <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">Bussiness Essentials</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Price">3.88 EUR / month</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Fully installed Office on PC / MAC">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Online Office">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="1 TB File Storage">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="HD video conferences">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Business email">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row"><a class="btn">choose</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">Business</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Price">5.00 EUR / month</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Fully installed Office on PC / MAC">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Online Office">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="1 TB File Storage">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="HD video conferences">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Business email">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row"><a class="btn">choose</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">Business Premium</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Price">7.00 EUR / month</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Fully installed Office on PC / MAC">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Online Office">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="1 TB File Storage">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="HD video conferences">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row" data-th="Business email">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row"><a class="btn">choose</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #col1 {
    display: none;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {}
  .col-sm-12 > div {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-12 > div:before {
    content: attr(data-th);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEJyyo